# Why doesen't pygame.display.fill() not work, when pygame.display is the main display object?

Tags: python, pygame

From my understanding, I know that `pygame.display` is the main pygame display window. So why doesn't `pygame.display.fill()` work in my code below?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

SCREEN_LENGTH = 800
SCREEN_WIDTH = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_LENGTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))
run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # change the background color
    **pygame.display.fill((0, 0, 255))**
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.display`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) is not the "main display window", but a module. The `pygame.disaply` module does not have a `fill` function. `fill` is a method of the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) class and therefore can only be called with an instance object of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill). [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) initializes the Pygame window and returns a `pygame.Surface` object. Everything drawn on this `pygame.Surface` object will be synchronized with the window when `pygams.disaply.update` or `pygame.disaply.flip` is called. After initializing the window, the same `pygame.Surface` object is also returned by [`pygame.display.get_surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface).

Therefore

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_LENGTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))

# [...]

screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
```

can be replaced with

```py
pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_LENGTH, SCREEN_WIDTH))

# [...]

pygame.display.get_surface().fill((0, 0, 255))
```

However, `pygame.display.fill((0, 0, 255))` makes no sense at all and causes an error.

Comment: So when I write pygame.display, I'm going into the pygame module then going into pygames display module then set_mode() creates an object of a display?

Comment: @HaseenSiddiqui `pygame.display.set_mode` initializes the Pygame window and  returns a `pygame.Surface`. Everything what is drawn on that surface is synced with the window when `pygams.disaply.update` or `pygame.disaply.flip` is called.